# mongodb and inserting values in collection with php

Tags: php, mongodb, collections

after connecting with Mongodb
  i have created database project
    =>use project
  then i have created collection
    =>db.createCollection("WaterMoneteringSystem",{capped:true,size:2147483648,max:20000})

then i want to enter the values into the collection via php
  so this is the code i have written

```
<?php
$d=$_POST['dte'];
$t=$_POST['tme'];
$PH=$_POST['ph'];
$TU=$_POST['tbdity'];
$RO=$_POST['RdcdOxdtn'];
if($PH>14 || $PH<0)
{
echo "error";
}
else
{
$m = new MongoClient();
echo "Connection to database successfully";
select a database
$db = $m->project;
echo "Database project selected";
$collection = $db->WaterMoneteringSystem;
echo "Collection selected succsessfully";
$document = array(
"Date" => "$d",
"Time" => "$t",
"PH" => "$PH",
"Turbidity" => "$TU",
"Reduced Oxidation" =>"$RO"
);
$collection->insert($document);
echo "Document inserted successfully";
}
?>
```

But this is not working

thank you

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Are you getting any data in your `$_POST` variables?  Also, the line `select a database` isn't commented out, so that'd throw an error.

Comment: the values arent going in the collection.

Comment: @Quixrick yeah i am getting values in the post.

Comment: @Quixrick select a database is backslashed

Comment: Well, don't know why this should make a difference, but one thing you can try is to remove the quotes around your variables.  `"Date" => $d,`.  This should not make a difference, though, but something you can try.  Who knows?  Everything else looks right to me.  I don't have a Mongo server here at work, but I can test this out in a few hours when I get home if you still don't have an answer by then.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I recreated what you had and it seemed to work for me.  Here is the exact code that I used:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient(); $db = $mongo->project;

$d = '2014-04-14';
$t = '18:14:00';
$PH = 7;
$TU = 'Huh What?';
$RO = 'yes';


if(($PH > 14) || ($PH < 0)) {
    echo "error";
}
else {

    $document = array(
        "Date" => $d,
        "Time" => $t,
        "PH" => $PH,
        "Turbidity" => $TU,
        "Reduced Oxidation" => $RO
    );


    $db->WaterMoneteringSystem->insert($document);


    echo "Document inserted successfully";

}
```

When I went to the database, everything was there as it should be:

[image: MongoDB Screenshot]

The only things that I did, really was to remove the quotes from the variables and just changed the way that it connects to the database.  Neither of those should have affected anything, though, so I'm not sure.  Try pasting my code into your script and see if that works.

I did, however, actually go back and use your exact code (with the exception of commenting out the `select a database` line and defining my own `$_POST` variables, since I do not have them) and it also inserted the record just fine.

That being said, it's got to be something with another part of your script that's wonky.  Are you able to select records from the DB?  Meaning, is your connection set up properly and you don't have to specify a host, username or password?  I'd suggest, checking there for problems.

Also, are you getting the "Document inserted successfully" message on your page?  When I ran your exact code, I got this:

```
Connection to database successfullyDatabase project selectedCollection selected succsessfullyDocument inserted successfully
```

Check to make sure your message looks like that as well.

Comment: thank you for helping me . but the thing is the value such as Date,time Ph,is given by the user so the $_POST has to be used.

Comment: That's not a problem; It shouldn't make a difference in this instance. Swap out what I have for $_POST and it will do the same thing. What i was suggesting is that the problem is somewhere else in your code and not with your MongoDB insert query. I was able to take your query and it inserted properly into MongoDB. I can't see what values you're putting in, but maybe try it with one value first or a hard-coded value and then slowly replace them in one by one to see if any of those are throwing off your query. If you can't insert with one single hard-coded value you know the problem is elsewhere